# Call to a member function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm receiving the following error message while trying to call a method from a Singleton class, inside another class.

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

Comment: Possible causes: using a global variable `$variable`, without using `global $variable` or `$GLOBALS['variable']`

Answer (score 3):

`$db` should become `$this->db`.

```
 public function __construct() {
    $this->db = Database::getInstance('localhost', 'database', 'root', '123456');
}
```

Comment: I now get Call to a member function query() on a non-object in Database.class.php

Comment: @Vinny: You have the same error there...  All member variables must be prefixed by `$this->` to be accessed within a method...

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$db` in constructor to `$this->db`. In PHP member properties are accessed by explicit reference to `$this` object.

Also, you have made the same mistake in your Database class. Additionally, specifying method connect() as static does not make much sense. In addition, if you ask me, `private` qualifier would be more appropriate than `public`. Finally, if you have no intention of handling the exception elsewhere just use `die()` instead of `echo`.

```
public function connect($server, $database, $user, $pass) {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error!";
    }  
}
```

In method `query()` also use `$this->pdo` instead of just `$pdo`.

Comment: I now get Call to a member function query() on a non-object in Database.class.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign and reference $pdo as $this->pdo in Database in addition to assigning $db to $this->db in your Users constructor.